# Is it possible to refresh zWeatherfeed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've noticed that many people are using zWeatherfeed to show live local weather on websites. I too am looking to implement this, alongside the current time, date and a twitter feed as I'm buildng something for a screen in our company reception area. The weather feed works however as this is staying on screen all day I'm trying to get it to refresh at regular intervals. I'd rather do this without having to refresh the whole page. The default code is below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#weatherbox').weatherfeed(['UKXX0117'],{
    unit: 'c',
});
```

});

```
<div id="weatherbox"></div>
```

This is what I've tried so far using setInterval to try and call the function again. It works to a point but creates another instance of the weatherfeed instead of refreshing the existing one. So I have to admit I'm stumped, any help would be greatly appreciated my current attempt is below.

```
setInterval( refreshFeed, 36000);

function refreshFeed() {
$('#weatherbox').weatherfeed(['UKXX0117'],{
    unit: 'c',
});

}
```

Comment: you might need to destroy the old one before creating a new one.

Comment: Took some time but I managed to sort it out. First by making zWeatherfeed run on page load, then creating a function that emptys the div then calls the function again every 5 minutes using setInterval. Thanks.